# Predicting class of email based on its associated parameters

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

[image]

I am solving a challenge where the data represented as above is given. In this challenge I have to associate each email with one of the the 2 criteria (automation, Or SEO). Example if email falls under SEO then I can reach out that person regarding SEO related queries.

I have these parameters associated with each email:

- Position of the person
- Organisation name
- Company domain

My task is to associate each email with one of the the 2 criteria (automation, Or SEO)

Some entries for Position (job title) are missing from my dataset. But I always have Organisation name and Company Domain and associated email.

To solve this I referred to a well known problem of predicting tags of a stack overflow post: https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/predicting-tags-for-the-questions-in-stack-overflow-29438367261e

But in my case is this approach suitable? How should I approach this problem with a better method?